# jQuery switch DIV element href click

Tags: jquery, html

**Hello Stackers,**

I'm having a jQuery problem, again. I'll try to have a MENU on the right, which should show the particular DIV Element. However, it just doesn't do anything, not even returning a Console log. jQuery is included from the Google Library.

**jQuery**

```
$().ready(function(){   
    $("#sedelnotif").hide();
    $("#staffnotif").hide();

    $('.allnotif').click(function(e) // bind a click event on the anchor tags
    {
      $("#allnotif").show(); 
      $("#sedelnotif").hide()
      $("#staffnotif").hide()
    });

     $('.sedelnotif').click(function(e) // bind a click event on the anchor tags
    {
      $("#sedelnotif").show(); 
      $("#allnotif").hide()
      $("#staffnotif").hide()
    });

     $('.staffnotif').click(function(e) // bind a click event on the anchor tags
    {
      $("#staffnotif").show(); 
      $("#allnotifn").hide()
      $("#sedelnotif").hide()
    });

  });
```

**HTML - The Menu**

```
  <a class="list-group-item" class="allnotif" href="#allnotif"><strong>Alle Notificaties</strong></a>
 <a class="list-group-item" class="sedelnotif" href="#sedelnotif">Gelezen & Verwijderd</a>
<a class="list-group-item" class="staffnotif" href="#staffnotif">Staffmededelingen</a>
```

**HTML - The DIV Which should change**

```
<div class="jumbotron"  style="width:80%; margin-left:-30px; margin-top:-19px;padding-bottom:30px;"> 
        <div id="allnotif">
            <?php if($notif_count < 1){ echo "<center><span class='help-block'>Je hebt op dit moment <u>geen</u> Notificaties<br><small style='color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);'>Maak je geen zorgen, je krijgt ze echt wel!</small></span></center>"; } ?>
        </div>
        <div id="sedelnotif">
            <?php if($notif_count < 1){ echo "<center><span class='help-block'>Je hebt op dit moment <u>geen</u> gelezen/verwijderde Notificaties<br><small style='color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);'>Je kan notificaties verwijderen of als gelezen markeren!</small></span></center>"; } ?>
        </div>
        <div id="staffnotif">
            <?php if($notif_count < 1){ echo "<center><span class='help-block'>Je hebt op dit moment <u>geen</u> Staffnotificaties<br><small style='color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);'>Spannend!</small></span></center>"; } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I want is that if someone clicks on another menu item, it shows that div and hides the others. What am I doing wrong?

Screenshot:
[image: The Notification Center]

Comment: Shouldn't `$().ready` be `$(document).ready`?

Comment: I've tried that, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Could you tell me where? I see the same classes as the Id's but could that be the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about my last comment

Comment: Are you using any CSS for the DIVS?

Comment: No problem! I'm already glad that someone is trying to help.

Comment: Only the main DIV, which isn't the code. That div has the following style, but does only apply on the parent:

`#notificationcenter {
 display:none;
 background-color: #F2F6F7;
 width:100%;
 height:220px;
 margin-top:70px;
}`Be aware, this is only the parent, which opens animated too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are assigning the class attribute twice to each of the links. jQuery parses the first class instead of the second, so they are just getting the class `.list-group-item` instead of `.allnotif`, `.sedelnotif` and `.staffnotif`. Here's what they should look like:

```
<a class="list-group-item allnotif" href="#allnotif"><strong>Alle Notificaties</strong></a>
<a class="list-group-item sedelnotif" href="#sedelnotif">Gelezen &nbsp; Verwijderd</a>
<a class="list-group-item staffnotif" href="#staffnotif">Staffmededelingen</a>
```

And a working Fiddle (without PHP obviously): https://jsfiddle.net/kcw9jhzk/

Comment: Thanks! I Didn't notice that. However, when clicking one link now it scrolls me down a little bit, leaving the "Notification Parent" only visible half, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: @PascalBoschma Sounds like some other CSS issue. Can you provide the CSS which might affect these elements? Also, do you have any other JS that interacts with these elements, and might perform a scroll? I don't see anything that would scroll the page currently...

Comment: That fiddle has basically no HTML... adding that CSS with the HTML from your original question (and a couple elements I added to reproduce your image, since you're not giving me all the code), I get this: https://jsfiddle.net/a8k75qj8/. I don't see the issue you're talking about. Also, as @isherwood mentions - this is a separate issue and should have a separate thread...

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks. This did fix my problem. Just overlooked it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two class attributes on each of your menu items. The second one is being ignored by jQuery.

```
<a class="list-group-item allnotif" href="#allnotif"><strong>Alle Notificaties</strong></a>
```

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3puygh7h/)**